# Why do we use a temporary box in prototype inheritance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

The function below is one that Derek Banas on youtube on his OO Javascript tutorial uses.

```
function extend(Child, Parent){
  var Temp = function(){};

  Temp.prototype = Parent.prototype;

  Child.prototype = new Temp();

  Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

}
```

Why must we use the Temp prototype?
Why can't we just do this:

```
function extend(Child, Parent){


  Child.prototype = new Parent();

  Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

}
```

Comment: There are still tutorials around that don't use `Object.create`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911926/why-is-new-parent-often-used-to-initialize-prototypes-of-children-instead-of-o

Comment: @Bergi I read the article that you linked explaining why the second one is bad, but I don't quite understand this statement: "Isn't it undesired to give different status to inherited properties vs own properties?" –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. The main difference in both the function are in the lines

```
Temp.prototype = Parent.prototype;
```

and `Child.prototype = new Parent();`

The first `extend` function shows prototypal inheritance solely. The `Child` wouldn't inherit any property from the `Parent`, which isn't there in its' prototype, as you can see, you are not calling the parent's `constructor` anywhere.

I have created a fiddle to explain this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ope56eu0/).

In the second extend function, as you are calling the Parent's `constructor` `Child.prototype = new Parent()`, all the properties of the `Parent`, which are there in Parent's prototype alongwith all those which aren't will be inherited by the `Child`; i.e it will all go into the Child's `prototype`.

I have created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ope56eu0/1/) to explain this as well.

Comment: I read @Bergi 's article that he linked explaining why the second one is bad, but I don't quite understand this statement:
"Isn't it undesired to give different status to inherited properties vs own properties?"

Comment: In my fiddle from the second option, you can probably see that you are getting all the prototype properties(referred as inherited), as well as own properties of Vehicle into the prototype properties of Car. Here you can't distinguish between those two. That is the concern of that statement..